# angularjs display different data from ng-repeat in table with two columns

Tags: angularjs

Have two different JSON data and want them to display in a two columns

```
data1 = [{id:one,n:1},{id:two,n:2},{id:three,n:3}]
data2 = [{id:one,n:1x},{id:two,n:2x},{id:three,n:3x}]

<tr ng-repeat='x in data1' ng-repeat='y in data2'>
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.n}}</td>
    <td>{{y.n}}</td>
</tr>
```

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 1 | 1x |
| two | 2 | 2x |
| three | 3 | 3x |

Answer (score 0):

If your data 1 and data 2 are going to be of the same length always you can take the following approach

```
$scope.data1 = [{id:one,n:1},{id:two,n:2},{id:three,n:3}];
$scope.data2 = [{id:one,n:1x},{id:two,n:2x},{id:three,n:3x}];

$scope.sizeLimit = $scope.data1.length;
```

in your html

```
<tr ng-repeat='i in [].constructor(sizeLimit) track by $index' >
    <td>{{data1[$index].id}}</td>
    <td>{{data1[$index].n}}</td>
    <td>{{data2[$index].n}}</td>
</tr>
```